# How to correctly link MSVC library

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, static-linking

I'm currently following instructions from a document and it says something like : add headers and library to your compiler.

I have the choice between those precompiled files : https://github.com/humancomputerintegration/rehamove-integration-lib/tree/master/hasomed_precompiled

I should choose the smpt_rm3_msvc2015_x86_32_static version since I'm on Windows 10.

As I choose smpt_rm3_msvc2015_x86_32_static, there are two folders inside of it. What should I do with those folders to properly link them with the main.c that I have ?

Thank you

Comment: You need to set your project properties to find these includes (the path) and that lib (path and lib name). The Includes in c++ properties section and the lib in the linker section.

Comment: Thank you, it worked